# How to access these section of Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a `firebase` project in `Android`  where I need to display all info of all users on list view.*(For the following case in which I've provided image, my list view will have 4 information fields.)*

[image]

But I don't know how to do that. I'm not understanding how to get `database reference` to the following fields **marked in green**(in provided image, for the user 2 it'll be same as for user1, just that I've not expanded the node) & also how to have the loop structure to do the same.

Btw, this is how I've entered data into Firebase Database:

In **MyActivity.java**

```
private void sendUserData()
{
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Deals");

    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(
        firebaseAuth.getUid(),
        name.getText().toString(),
        contact.getText().toString(),
        address.getText().toString(),
        startDate.getText().toString(),
        endDate.getText().toString()
    );

    databaseReference.child(formatter.format(date)).setValue(userProfile);
}
```

Now, I wanna retrieve but I don't know how because I've never used Firebase before. I'm referring tutorials, but they don't address my problem.

Comment: I recommend you read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/). You should build a class containing what an user object holds.

Comment: Yea... Actually I have made a class. From tutorials I understood that we need a class... But rest I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Firebase, if you want to show a list of something, you will have to have a list of those things in the database. So if you want to show a list of users, you should have a list of users in the database (which you do). That means you can show all users easily with a listener like this:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

You can also loop over the child nodes of each user in the `onDataChange` with:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
        for (DataSnapshot dealSnapshot: userSnapshot.child("Deals").getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(dealSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

You'll note that we're now using two nested loops, since the data is two levels deep.

To display the data in your app, you will need to add the data to an adapter. For many use-cases you can use the [adapters from FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database), which can display data from lists. This can be used with your data structure to show the list of users for example.

However the adapters in FirebaseUI require that the data you're showing is in a single list. So it *can* display the list of users, it *can* display the list of deals for a specific user (see [this question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344827/how-to-retrieve-my-data-inside-the-random-key)), but it **can't** display a single list of deals across all users, because you don't have that list in your database.

If the latter is what you're trying to do, you will either need to create your own adapter, or you will need to store the deals for all users as a single list in the database. For example, the FirebaseUI adapters could show `Deals` with the below structure:

```
Deals
    deal1id: { user: "userId1", ... }
    deal2id: { user: "userId2", ... }
    deal3id: { user: "userId1", ... }
    deal4id: { user: "userId2", ... }
UserDeals
    userId1
        deal1id: true
        deal3id: true
    userId2
        deal2id: true
        deal4id: true
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This indeed was very very helpful. I'll look for whatever you warned me about. Thank you so much again!!! :)