# How to retrieve my data inside the random key?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the data inside the random key, as shown here:

[image: description]

I am using Firebase and I have tried a lot of things, but I cannot solve this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView , recyclerView1 ;
    public DatabaseReference ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        {
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests");
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(
                    Food.class,
                    R.layout.individual_row,
                    FoodViewHolder.class,
                    ref
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {

                    viewHolder.setProductName(model.getProductName());
                    viewHolder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());

                }
            };
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests");
        recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_foods);
        recyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(
                Food.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,
                FoodViewHolder.class,
                ref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setProductName(model.getProductName());
                viewHolder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());

            }
        };
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView text_productName , text_quantity , text_customername;
        public FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text_productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
            text_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_qty);


        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            text_productName.setText(productName);

        }

        public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
                text_quantity.setText(quantity);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean sir?

Comment: you want to get it in android ?

Comment: Can you give me some sample code to make me undestand thank you

Comment: Yes in android sir

Comment: in android application kindly show your code where you want to get this

Comment: I want to retrieve the data inside the node of the random key

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried

Comment: I edited the post kindly see the post sir I paste there the code

Comment: Can you make the code how to retrieve that data sir? I a beginner I dont undestand much in android development

Comment: Check that one also[link](https://android.jlelse.eu/fetch-data-from-firebase-cloud-firestore-to-recyclerview-using-firestorerecycleradapter-5fe6e03e32e4)

Comment: Can you write the sample code sir?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an adapter on `Requests`. That means that the recycler view will show a **list of requests**: so one row for each request. But you created a data class `Food` and a `FoodViewHolder`, so it seems you actually want to display a **list of foods**.

To display a list of foods in your recycler view, you must have a list of foods in your database. For example, you can show the foods for the first request by determining the `DatabaseReference` to that request and then showing that in the adapter:

```
DatabaseReference requestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests");
Query firstRequestQuery = requestsRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);
firstRequestQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot requestSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(
                Food.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,
                FoodViewHolder.class,
                requestSnapshot.getRef().child("foods")
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setProductName(model.getProductName());
                viewHolder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

While there may be some problems with the code, it demonstrates how to show the foods of the first request in the recycler view. The key is `requestSnapshot.getRef().child("foods")`, which ensures the adapter loads the foods of the first request.

Comment: How can I retrieve all the data under the random key sir? Specially the productName and qty. I want to retrieve all the productName and qty under that random key in recyclerview hope you help me

Comment: How does this comment relate to what I explained in my answer?

Comment: Because my question is how to retrieve the data inside random key.

Comment: Hi sir what should I put on FoodViewHolder?